# How to transfer my account?

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

I have completed the tutorial on GTA V in story mode, but when I press transfer character, it says I have already transferred to Sony PlayStation. (New account I'm trying to transfer to is to PS4, old one is Xbox One, and I am signed into Social Club).

Answer (score 1):

You can only transfer character once, unless your second transfer is to PC.
And I am not sure, but it probably only allows transfers in one of these two flows:

xbox 360 -> xbox one -> PC

ps3 -> ps4 -> pc